# SQL Server case sum query

Tags: sql-server, loops

**UPDATE**
*I've managed to get 1 or 0 depending on the count, but it is not separated by "Servicio" column so everything has 1 or 0 if there is any row matching...*

I have the following query which is not working... It never stops executing, what I want is to add 0 or 1 to each "Servicios" column...

I have three tables, "Banksphere", "PAS" and "CAM" with relationship with "Entidades" and "Servicios"

PAS and CAM does not have "servicio_id" but I fix that using the "Join" for Servicios... That's OK "Servicio" for PAS is 3, and CAM is 0.

I hope I've explained it good... I can't do better now, I'm not on my PC

Example:

```
Banksphere [ id | entidad_id | servicio_id | reconocido ]
           [ 1  |     3      |      9      |     0      ]
           [ 2  |     1      |      1      |     1      ]
           [ 3  |     4      |      6      |     0      ]

PAS        [ id | entidad_id | reconocido ]
           [ 1  |     3      |     0      ]
           [ 2  |     5      |     1      ]
           [ 3  |     4      |     0      ]

CAM        [ id | entidad_id | reconocido ]
           [ 1  |     0      |     1      ]
           [ 2  |     0      |     1      ]
           [ 3  |     0      |     1      ]
```

The resulset I want is this one....

```
[ Entidad | Servicio | Alertas ]
[    0    |     0    |    1    ]
[    1    |     1    |    1    ]
[    3    |     9    |    0    ]
[    3    |     3    |    0    ]
[    4    |     6    |    0    ]
[    4    |     3    |    0    ]
[    5    |     3    |    1    ]
```

Can someone help me? Thank you very much...

```
SELECT DISTINCT entidad, value, alertas
FROM   (SELECT Entidades.id AS entidad,
    Servicios.nombre AS servicio1,
    sp.nombre AS servicio2,
    sc.nombre AS servicio3,
    CASE WHEN (
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(Banksphere.reconocido) FROM Banksphere WHERE Banksphere.reconocido = '0' AND Banksphere.fecha = '2012-12-18') = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    + CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PAS.reconocido) FROM PAS WHERE PAS.reconocido = '0' AND PAS.fecha = '2012-12-18') = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    + CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(CAM.reconocido) FROM CAM WHERE CAM.reconocido = '0' AND CAM.fecha = '2012-12-18') = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS alertas
FROM   Entidades
LEFT JOIN (Banksphere INNER JOIN Servicios
    ON ( Banksphere.servicio_id = Servicios.id ))
    ON Entidades.id = Banksphere.entidad_id
    AND Banksphere.fecha = '2012-12-18'
LEFT JOIN (CAM
    INNER JOIN Servicios sc
ON ( sc.nombre = 'CAM' ))
ON Entidades.id = CAM.entidad_id
    AND CAM.fecha = '2012-12-18'
LEFT JOIN (PAS
    INNER JOIN Servicios sp
ON ( sp.nombre = 'PAS' ))
ON Entidades.id = PAS.entidad_id
GROUP  BY Entidades.id,
    Entidades.nombre,
    Servicios.nombre,
    sp.nombre,
    sc.nombre,
    Banksphere.reconocido,
    PAS.reconocido,
    CAM.reconocido
)
src 
UNPIVOT ( value FOR col IN (servicio1, servicio2, servicio3) ) unpiv
GROUP BY alertas, entidad, value
ORDER  BY entidad ASC, value ASC
```

Comment: Can you post your table structures, sample data and then the desired result of the query?  Even better create a [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with a working data model.

Comment: Agree with bluefeet. A query like this is impossible to evaluate without working sample data.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate or a very similar repeat of your previous question: [SQL Server count values with join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921622/sql-server-count-values-with-join)

Comment: It is similar, the query changed with few elements so I needed to create a new one. Also I've updated my post to see what I want..